# Test Notification messages in android using JUnit

Tags: android, junit, notifications

I am writing JUnit test cases for my android application.

Here i need to verify notification functionality of my application. I can't find any way to doing this using JUnit.

Please share any ideas to verify the notification messages in android test application.